# How to get Team Id in the Teams powerapps

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, powerapp, microsoft-teams, powerapps-forms

I want to find the Current Team id in the Teams Power Apps.

Please help me to get the Team ID from the Teams Power apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Team's context variables with the `Param()` function.

You can get teams group ID like:

```
Set(groupId, Param("groupId"))
```

**Documentation**: [Use context from Teams](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/teams/embed-teams-app#use-context-from-teams)

---

I just create a canvas app from Microsoft Teams Power Apps >> Published it to Teams channel and I am able to get the `groupId`. Here's screenshot of working app:

[image]

I have added above formula in `OnStart` property of `App`.

Comment: Hi Ganesh,

It's not Standalone Canvas app. this app is created in the powerapps section of teams. there the above Set(groupId, Param("groupId")) is not working

Comment: I just tried creating Power Apps in Microsoft Teams & it works for me. check updated answer for screenshot of working app.

Comment: Can you please **[Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments)** and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily.